# mysql copy value from one table to another gives me error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to copy a value from table2 to table1 with a trigger before table 1 gets inserted with a data, the problem that I have is that whenever I insert a new row into table1 I get an error saying that the column can't be null, in my case the column is color.
Just fyi table 1 has a column named 'color' as well as table 2

This is the code I have

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER `some_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.color = 
(
    SELECT table2.color
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.aforeignkeycolumn = table2.aprimarykeycolumn
    WHERE table1.id = new.id  --this should be the new row
);
END;
```

If I had this it would work but I need to get the id of the row thats about to get insert it into table 1

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER `some_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.color = 
(
    SELECT table2.color
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.aforeignkeycolumn = table2.aprimarykeycolumn
    WHERE table1.id = 10
);
END;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing an *after insert* trigger?

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `some_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT new.color := table2.color
    FROM table1 JOIN
         table2
          ON table1.aforeignkeycolumn = table2.aprimarykeycolumn
    WHERE table1.id = new.id  --this should be the new row
END;
```

Comment: I am getting this error. "updating a NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

Comment: I think that is why I am using 'Before insert on' I just need to know the id thats going to be inserted next'

Comment: Why are you putting the value in the table instead of looking it up dynamically when you need it?

Comment: What do you mean looking it up dynamically? I need to store the value in the table so that another query can do other stuff with it

Comment: @user3768541 . . . Just use a join in the query to get the value.